# How to put variable text and custom text together in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If there is an inherited variable called id, I would like to display widget.index and ": problem number" together on one line on the screen.

ex)
**problem(text) 1(list variable)**

**problem(text) 2(list variable)**

Is there a way to get a variable in a list like the one above and display it on the screen along with text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $ in a string

```
      String someString = 'problem id: ${problem(text)} and widget index :${widget.index}';
```